# get an arraylist from a service using HTTP in ANGULAR

Tags: json, angular, http, service

i have a component named zoomdetails which contains the specific details of a product 
 when i click on the product image the zoomdetails component displays and contains the details of the clicked product

so i m using route and adding the id of the product to the URL

the problem is :

when i load the products arraylist from the service and try to get the product by its id and looping the arraylist an error appears and indicates **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

here is the zoomdetails.component.ts code : 
(i ve added some log.console comments to see the results)

```js
export class ZoomdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  x: string="";
produitzoom:IProduct;
produits:IProduct[];
errormessage1 :string ;
currentId : number;

constructor(private _route:ActivatedRoute,private _router:Router,private _productServic:ProductdataService)
{ 
  console.log("Logging the route : " + JSON.stringify(_route.snapshot.params));
  this.currentId = +_route.snapshot.params['id'];
  console.log("Logging the current ID : " + this.currentId)
   this._productServic.getProducts()
    .subscribe(productss => this.produits=productss ,error=>this.errormessage1= <any>error);
    console.log("************************************************************************************")
 
  
}
  
Myspan(){
  
 this._router.navigate(['/']);


}

find (id:number,P:IProduct[]) :IProduct{
  console.log("+++++++DANS FIND ERROR +++++++++++++++++++++++++")
  
  for (let product of P )
   {
      if (product.idpr==id )
      { 
        return product;
      }
   }
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("-------------DANS NGONINITTT-------------------------------------------------------------")

    this.produitzoom=this.find(this.currentId,this.produits)
    console.log(this.produitzoom.productName)
    console.log("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  
  
}
```

and this is my zoomdetails component .html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div id="zoom" class="modal">
  
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" (click)="Myspan()">&times;</span>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div  class="col-md-4 item-photo">
            
            <img  src={{produitzoom.imgUrl}} style="width:360px;height:650px;">
            
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6" style="border:0px solid rgba(163, 152, 152, 0.856)">
            <span class="pull-right">
            <!-- Datos del vendedor y titulo del producto -->
            <h1>{{produitzoom.productName}}</h1>    
            <h4 style="color:#337ab7"> {{produitzoom.author}} <small style="color:#337ab7">(50 ventes)</small></h4>
      
            <!-- Precios -->
            <h2 class="title-price"><small>Price</small></h2>
            <h3 style="margin-top0px">{{produitzoom.price}} $</h3>
            <br> <br>
      
            <!-- Detalles especificos del producto -->
            <div class="section" style="background:rgb(222, 228, 222);">
              <h5 class="title-attr" >                  
              <div>
                <br>
               {{produitzoom.description}}
              <br> <br>
              </div>
            </h5>  
            </div>
            <br><br> 
            <!-- Botones de compra -->     
                  <script>
                  console.log("Test of value : " + JSON.stringify(produitzoom))
                  </script>
                    <button class="btn  btn-success right" [routerLink]="['/Authentification',produitzoom]">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to Cart
                    </button> 
          </span>                                      
          <br> <br>      <br> <br>                        
            <ul class="menu-items">
            
              <li class="active">Customers Reviews</li>
              
            </ul>
            <div style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid silver">
              <p style="padding:15px;">
                <small>
                Stay connected either on the phone or the Web with the Galaxy S4 I337 from Samsung. With 16 GB of memory and a 4G connection, this phone stores precious photos and video and lets you upload them to a cloud or social network at blinding-fast speed. With a 17-hour operating life from one charge, this phone allows you keep in touch even on the go. 
   
                With its built-in photo editor, the Galaxy S4 allows you to edit photos with the touch of a finger, eliminating extraneous background items. Usable with most carriers, this smartphone is the perfect companion for work or entertainment.
                </small>
              </p>
              
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  
    
  </div>
```

and these are the errors :

```
Logging the route : {"id":"1"} zoomdetails.component.ts:22 Logging the current ID : 1 zoomdetails.component.ts:25 ************************************************************************************ zoomdetails.component.ts:50 -------------DANS NGONINITTT------------------------------------------------------------- zoomdetails.component.ts:38 +++++++DANS FIND ERROR +++++++++++++++++++++++++ ZoomdetailsComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (from the find method )
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'imgUrl' of undefined (from the html file produitzoom.imgurl)

what should i do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, about the `imgUrl` error, because of the fact that initially `produitzoom` is undefined, and it gets it's value after an async call, you can change the value of binding to this: `[src]="produitzoom? produitzoom.imgUrl : null"`.

also about the other error, you are calling `this.produitzoom=this.find(this.currentId,this.produits)` inside your `ngOnInit` function, but again, bacuase of the fact that the `produits` is also undefined at the beginning of the component's lifecycle, and gets it's value after an async call. you should move that `this.find()` call over to the subscribtion's success. something like this:

```
productss => {
    this.produits=productss;
    this.produitzoom = this.find(this.currentId,this.produits)
}
```

**Note!!**

it's also very important and recommended that if you are subscribing to an observable, you unsubscribe it at the end of that component's Lifecycle (inside `ngOnDestroy` function). otherwise, this would cause memory leeks and untracable errors... you can do that by defining a property for subscription like: 
`productsSubscription: Subscription;`
dont forget to import `Subscription` from `rxjs/subscription`. and then assign the subscription to this property like:

```
this.productsSubscription = this._productServic.getProducts()
    .subscribe(.....);
```

and inside ngOnDestroy:

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.productsSubscription){
        this.productsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

have that `if` there to prevent any undefined-related errors.

Comment: happy to help.
also, you can accept/upvote answer if it's helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are loading the products in your constructor, which is asynchronous. Then in your `ngOnInit` function that is called later on you're using the result of those loaded products, but unfortunately they seem to be not loaded yet. Therefore your `P` array is not existing yet and so you are using an undefined object in a for loop, which is not working.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("-------------DANS NGONINITTT-------------------------------------------------------------")

    // --> here you use the products from the constructor
    // but they are not loaded yet, because the loading process takes time and is asynchronous
    this.produitzoom=this.find(this.currentId,this.produits)
    console.log(this.produitzoom.productName)
    console.log("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")


}
```

What you should do is place the loading of your products in the `ngOnInit` function as well. There you can wait for the result and *then* call the find function.

```
nOnInit(){
    // don't subscribe in the constructor, do it in the ngOnInit
    this._productServic.getProducts().subscribe(productss => {
            // now the results are here and you can use them
            this.produits = productss;
            // only then you can call the find function safely
            this.produitzoom = this.find(this.currentId, this.produits)
        }, error => this.errormessage1 = <any>error);
}
```